# Replace every letter of string with next letter in alphabet but preserve spaces and punctuation?

Tags: java

I need to replace every letter in the file with the next letter in the alphabet (no numbers are used so no concern there). However I am supposed to preserve spaces and punctuation. The code works fine to change the letters but i am unsure of how to preserve the spaces and punctuation. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

class Thirteen{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{

        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keystwo;

        System.out.println("Please enter an input file name");
        String filename = keys.next();
        File infile = new File(filename);
        keystwo = new Scanner(infile);

        System.out.println("Please enter an output filename");
        String outputfile = keys.next();
        File outfile = new File(outputfile);

        FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        PrintWriter display = new PrintWriter(outstream);

        while(keystwo.hasNext()){

            String one = keystwo.next().toLowerCase();
            //convert to stringbuilder to edit
            StringBuilder fine = new StringBuilder(one);

            for(int A = 0; A < fine.length(); A++){

                //read in as character
                char B = fine.charAt(A);
                //convert to ASCII
                int two = (int)B;
                //add one
                int convert = two+1;
                //convert to char
                char C = (char)convert;
                if(C == '{'){
                    C = 'a';
                }
                //print char & add to output file
                display.print(Character.toString(C));
                System.out.print(Character.toString(C));
            }//end for
        }//end while

        keystwo.close();
        display.close();
    }
}//end
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you apply the conversion to the current character in the string, you can check if it's a letter like so:

```
if(Character.isLetter(character))
{
//Do conversion here
}
```

That way the conversion will only be applied to letters.

Answer (score 0):

Bring char C up.  Convert B to a String.  Then match string on the regular expression.  \\s is for whitespace \\p{Punct} is for punctuation.  Square brackets means it is looking for one of the items inside.

```
    String charAsString = Character.toString(B);
    char C = B;
    if (!charAsString.matches("[\\s\\p{Punct}]"))
    {
      // convert to ASCII
      int two = (int) B;
      // add one
      int convert = two + 1;
      // convert to char
      C = (char) convert;
      if (C == '{')
      {
        C = 'a';
      }
      // print char & add to output file
    }
    display.print(Character.toString(C));
    System.out.print(Character.toString(C));
```